# Http 1.1 connection and client port

Tags: http, tcp, connection, port

Does the client remote port changes during an HTTP 1.1 connection exchange?

I am trying to figure out if I can programmaticaly uniquely identify a connection on the server using the request remote port and remote ip address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not as much an HTTP question, as it's a TCP one. And no, the port doesn't change: the [ephemeral port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) stays the same for the duration of the connection.

However, as soon as a new connection is made, the client *can* (and most probably *will*) use a different port. This totally depends on the implementation of the client OS and the Network Address Translation of intermediary routers.

Anyway, it is not something you can depend on to build something like a session, because the next request from the same client may very well arrive from a different port (let alone that HTTP does not have to run on top of TCP).

Just use a session-ID which you store in a cookie.